# Http POST and "Accept"

Tags: json, http-headers

When sending a POST request to a web server, can you specify the `Accept` header parameter alongside `Content-type`? As in, I am sending some JSON, so I'll specify that in `Content-type`, but since I expect a response from the server (perhaps the object that will be added to the database), I would specify that in the `Accept` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

> When sending a POST request to a web server, can you specify the Accept header parameter alongside Content-type?

Yes. Accept is what you will accept in the response. Content-Type is what you are sending in the request. They are entirely independent.

Comment: So, a POST request certainly can have an `Accept` parameter. Thanks.